# Color edges of a tree

Tags: r, minimum-spanning-tree, vegan

Using `vegan` to create minimum spanning tree:

```
library(vegan)
MST <- spantree(D)
```

where D is a distance / dissimilarity matrix amongst N entities.

I then plot using:

```
plot(MST, type = "t")
```

I now want to color the different nodes of the tree, depending on a label I have in `DataSet$SubGroups`, indicating which subgroup each of the N entities belong to. So that for instance, for all entities for which `DataSet$SubGroups == SubGroup1`, I want their label to be Green, for Subgroup2 Blue etc.

I tried with nodelabels from the ape package, but no luck as I get:

> ```
> Error in get("last_plot.phylo", envir = .PlotPhyloEnv) :    object
> 'last_plot.phylo' not found
> ```

Anybody any idea on how to get the color right?

Is it also possible to specify RGB color codes?

Comment: Do you need to `dput()` a data object? When I run your `spantree` code it throws an error and I believe it's using `D` from the stats package.

Comment: The reason for the error is that `ape` package works with objects of class `phylo` and `vegan::spantree` produces a `spantree` object. Check the discussion [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/18876/) for tips that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @nya. I am trying something like: 

    plot(MST, nodeAttrs=list(fillcolor = "lightblue"))

but no luck. THoughts? Ho can I tie this in with the DataSet$SubGroups ?

Comment: @RP13, you must select the toolset you try to use. You indicate that `MST` is a `vegan::spantree` object and for that **R** will use `vegan:::plot.spantree` which does not have `nodeAttrs` argument (some other `plot` method may have, but it probably does not know what to do with `vegan::spantree` objects). The `plot` command in vegan has arguments  `x` for the `spantree` result, `ord` for the coordinates of nodes (points) in the plot,  and `col` for the **colours** of points (nodes) and connecting lines (edges) in the plot.